# Coroutine never calls API after once API is failed

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, rx-java, kotlin-coroutines

In my viewmodel i've a function which uses coroutine to call an API.

```
fun loadPosts(){

    GlobalScope.launch(coroutineContext){
        changeState(load = true)
        val list= withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            apiService.getProfile(AUTH)
        }
        changeState(false,false,null)
        showResult(list)
    }
}
```

Everytime i click on a button, this function is fired, API is called and I get valid response. But once my api get Exception like 500 or Http 401 Unauthorized, then again when I hit the button, Coroutine is never called and seems it returns the again error message from cache.

For a use case:

I clicked on button -> Api is called  -> got success response

Again I clicked on  -> Api is called  -> got success response

I disconnected my internet from phone

I clicked on button -> Api is called -> got exception something like ConnectionError

I connected my phone to internet

I clicked on button -> **Api is not called** -> got exception something like ConnectionError

Now even my phone has valid internet connection, I press on button, instead of calling api and wait for response, It gives me previous failed response again and again.

**Earlier I was using Rxjava and I didn't face any such issue in that. I am new to coroutines so if anyone have any suggestion you are most welcome**

Comment: What's in the `coroutineContext` that you're placing in the `CoroutineScope()` call? My suspicion is that you have a regular `Job` instance in there, inside the context.

Comment: coroutineContext is defined in my BaseViewModel   like                             abstract class BaseViewModel : ViewModel(), CoroutineScope{

    private val job: Job= Job()
    
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = **Dispatchers.Main + job + handler**
     _ _ _ _

Comment: do you use `SupervisorJob`? you should use `SupervisorJob` to avoid error propagation from child coroutines. otherwise, when child make a exception, your root job would be cancelled.

Comment: SupervisorJob? this one is new for me it. Let me check it.

Comment: @Choim Thanks a lot. Seems it is working fine now. I just replaced Job() to SuperivsorJob() and its working fine now. Don't know magic behind yet happy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you start a coroutine with a coroutine builder such as `launch`, you need to start it in a given `CoroutineScope` - this is enforced by the function being [defined as an extension on `CoroutineScope`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html). This scope contains a `CoroutineContext`, which will define how the coroutine is executed.

Based on the comment above, I assume you are using roughly this setup:

```
abstract class BaseViewModel : ViewModel(), CoroutineScope { 
    private val job: Job = Job()
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext 
        get() = Dispatchers.Main + job

    override fun onCleared() {
        coroutineContext.cancel()
    }
}
```

By using `GlobalScope.launch(coroutineContext)`, you're actually overriding everything provided by `GlobalScope` with the context parameter. Plus, since your `ViewModel` itself is a scope already, you don't need to `launch` in `GlobalScope` in the first place. You can simply write down `launch` within the `ViewModel` with no scope specified (essentially `this.launch {}`) and no context passed to it, as it will get the one from the scope anyway.

The other issue is that you're using a regular `Job` as a part of your `CoroutineContext`. This `Job` becomes a parent for every coroutine you start, and whenever a child coroutine fails, such as on a network error, the parent `Job` gets cancelled too - meaning that any further children you attempt to start will fail immediately as well, as you can't start a new child under an already failed `Job` (see the [`Job` documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/index.html) for more details).

To avoid this, you can use a [`SupervisorJob`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-supervisor-job.html) instead, which can also group your coroutines together as children, and cancel them when the `ViewModel` is cleared, but won't get cancelled if one of its children fail.

---

So to sum up the fixes to make at the code level quickly:

- Use a `SupervisorJob` in the `ViewModel` (and while you're there, create this combined `CoroutineContext` just once, by directly assigning it, and not placing it in a getter):

  ```
  override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main + SupervisorJob()
  ```
- Launch your coroutines in the scope defined in the `ViewModel` instead of in `GlobalScope`:

  ```
  abstract class BaseViewModel : ViewModel(), CoroutineScope { 
       // ...

      fun load() {
          launch { // equivalent to this.launch, because `this` is a CoroutineScope
              // do loading
          }
      }
  }
  ```

---

You may also want to consider having your `ViewModel` contain a `CoroutineScope` instead of implementing the interface itself, [as described here](https://proandroiddev.com/why-your-class-probably-shouldnt-implement-coroutinescope-eb34f722e510) an [discussed here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1581).

---

There's a lot of reading to do on this topic, here are some articles I usually recommend:

- https://medium.com/@elizarov/coroutine-context-and-scope-c8b255d59055
- https://medium.com/@elizarov/the-reason-to-avoid-globalscope-835337445abc
- https://proandroiddev.com/demystifying-coroutinecontext-1ce5b68407ad

... and everything else by Roman Elizarov on his blog, really :)

Comment: I think there's no point anymore in recommending the long-hand style of implementing `CoroutineScope`, the new way with `by MainScope` has the same semantics with less boilerplate. On the other hand, the composition vs. inheritance styles each have their own advantages and neither is an all-round winner.

Answer (score 0):

One more option.

If you use `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0`, `ViewModel` now has `viewModelScope` extension property use `SupervisorJob` default. And it will be cleared automatically when `ViewModel` cleared.

Comment: So you mean to say I don't need to use Job() or SupervisorJob() as my coroutine will be cleared automatically as soon as viewmodel is cleared

Comment: @AnkitDubey yes, because `viewModelScope` use `SupervisorJob` internally.